# ROC curve in un-balanced data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I used ovr-classification with Gradient Boosting Classifier to predict a target value that is in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Majrotiy of data (2M samples) has a target value in {0, 1} and minority of data (97K samples) has a target value in {2, 3, 4, 5}. I have plotted ROC curves according to [Scikit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py). As the plot shows, minority classes have AUC=0.99. I'm wondering does it mean the performance of classifiers is high or it is the effect of unbalanced data?

[image]
**Update:** 
If I select the samples that have target value in {2, 3, 4, 5}, the ROC curve would be as bellows:
[image]

Comment: There is something called "the accuracy paradox". You can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox. Think that you have one class of 99 samples and a 2nd one with 1 sample. Even if your algorithm is based on random guess, it will still have a 99% accuracy.

Comment: I guess in the case that you mentioned, the accuracy of major class would be 99%, while in my case, the accuracy of the minor class is 99%.

Comment: Just to add to @Tasos' comment: average precision is often a more meaningful performance metric for unbalanced data sets (`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve` and `sklearn.metrics.average_precision`).

Comment: @Paul. Thank you. Yes,  average precision works.